# Multi time series table in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, geospatial, spatial

I have a table containing 100 monthly records for 30 raining gauges, and each gauge has its location (x,y). How can I load this table into R as a data frame?

My table:

```
ID:         g1,     g2,      g3,      ................     g30 

x:        50.635,  50.624,  50.68,    .............                   49.84

y:        120.8,   120.9,   120.3,    .............                   120.56

1/2000:    2.2,     2.3,     2,       ..............                      1

2/2000:    2.1,     1.6,     1.2,     ...............                    1.3

.
.
.
.

4/2008
```

Comment: What do you mean you have a table? Have it where? In R? In another program? In what format? Text? Excel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to read in an excel file. Please clarify your request with more detail. If it is excel, use this solution:

```
# Loading
library("readxl")
# xls files
my_data <- read_excel("my_file.xls")
# xlsx files
my_data <- read_excel("my_file.xlsx")
```